# Combine Subscriber not receiving values immediately

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, combine

I am trying to come up with a Combine pipeline that does the following

- Make an API call with certain pageIndex and send the results to subscriber
- Increment the page Index and repeat the above until backend says there is nothing more to fetch

Here is what I have done so far

```
struct APIResponse {
  var hasNextPage: Bool = false
  var nextPageIndex: Int = -1
}
class Tester {
    func getAllDetails() -> AnyPublisher<APIResponse, Never> {
        // Subject holding the page index to be fetched
        let subject = CurrentValueSubject<Int, Never>(0)
        
        return subject.flatMap ({ index in
            return self.getDetails(index: index)
        })
        .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { response in
            if response.hasNextPage {
                subject.send(response.nextPageIndex)
            } else {
                subject.send(completion: .finished)
            }
        })
 // Ignore the call, Just did it please the compiler
        .replaceError(with: APIResponse())
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    func getDetails(index: Int) -> AnyPublisher<APIResponse,MockError> {
        Future { promise in
            // Mocking API Response here
            if index < 5 {
                promise(.success(APIResponse(hasNextPage: true, nextPageIndex: index+1)))
            } else if index == 5 {
                promise(.success(APIResponse(hasNextPage: false)))
            } else {
                promise(.failure(MockError()))
            }
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

let tester =  Tester()
tester.getAllDetails()
    .sink { _ in
        print("completed")
    } receiveValue: { numbers in
        print(numbers.debugDescription)
    }
```

The pipeline is working but it delivering all the results to subscriber at the end and not as they arrive. How do I change this to let subscriber receive intermediate values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything wrong with your pipeline.  Your problem is that your mock API call isn't realistic; A real API call will be asynchronous.  Once you introduce asynchronous behaviour into your mock, you will get the result you expect:

```
func getDetails(index: Int) -> AnyPublisher<APIResponse,MockError> {
    Future { promise in
        DispatchQueue.global(qos:.utility).asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.5) {
                // Mocking API Response here
            if index < 5 {
                promise(.success(APIResponse(hasNextPage: true, nextPageIndex: index+1)))
            } else if index == 5 {
                promise(.success(APIResponse(hasNextPage: false)))
            } else {
                promise(.failure(MockError()))
            }
        }
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

```
APIResponse(hasNextPage: true, nextPageIndex: 1)
APIResponse(hasNextPage: true, nextPageIndex: 2)
APIResponse(hasNextPage: true, nextPageIndex: 3)
APIResponse(hasNextPage: true, nextPageIndex: 4)
APIResponse(hasNextPage: true, nextPageIndex: 5)
APIResponse(hasNextPage: false, nextPageIndex: -1)
completed
```

You will also need to ensure that your subscriber is retained:

```
var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

let tester =  Tester()
tester.getAllDetails()
    .sink { _ in
        print("completed")
    } receiveValue: { numbers in
        print(numbers)
    }.store(in: &cancellables)
```